# yaml_emit_file() not working. Call to undefined function yaml_emit_file()

Tags: php, composer-php, yaml, pecl

The php function `yaml_emit_file()` is not working. I have installed and included the `php_yaml.dll` in my `php.ini` file restarted the server but still when I use this function, I get this error (when I run composer):

```
Call to undefined function RS\composer\yaml_emit_file()
```

Okay so a little about the background:

PHP version 7.1.7 & Composer version 1.5.1

I am using this function in a ScriptHandler.php file which is invoked when `Composer` is run. In this script I have a function `buildModuleList` which is called on `post-update-cmd` event of `Composer`. Everything else in the code is working fine.

I am in doubt that maybe I am using this function in wrong context or something like that.

Here is the code snippet where I am using `yaml_emit_file()` (Providing this just for reference, tell me if am using it the wrong way!):

```
if (!$fs->exists($moduleListFile)) {
  $fs->touch($root.'/profiles/thunder/modulelist.yml');
  $fs->chmod($root . '/profiles/thunder/modulelist.yml', 0666);

  if(!empty($moduleList)){
    $createyml= yaml_emit_file($moduleListFile, $moduleList);
    if (!$createyml){
      $io->writeError('<error>Cannot create modulelist.yml</error>');
    }
  }
  $io->write('Success: Created new modulelist.yml', $newline= TRUE);
}
else{
  $fs->file_put_contents($moduleListFile, $installedPackage, FILE_APPEND);
  $io->write('Success: Module entry in modulelist.yml', $newline= TRUE);
}
```

Comment: The PHP process executed from the command line probably uses a different `php.ini` file than the web context. Did you make sure to update the proper file?

Comment: I'm running xampp, and the php is being executed from that only. Even the system environment path variable for php is the one in the xampp. So there's no problem there

Comment: I know that this question is old but please edit the question title to mention that you are in XAMPP on Windows :) So other people will answer about that 
(I was about replying about Linux, that is sudo apt install php-yaml)

Answer (score 0):

i hope this help someone i test it on
Windows 10
XAMPP v3.2.4
PHP 8.0.2

Download the latest YAML DLL Package from : https://pecl.php.net/package/yaml
Unzip the files

Move the php_yaml.dll file to xampp/php/ext folder
Open your php.ini in xampp/php add a new line extension=php_yaml.dll, save and exit
Restart your XAMPP Servers
make a PHP file put into

```
<?php 
   phpinfo();
?>
```

Search the string yaml on the page. If it says Enabled then your YAML Extension is working.